# How to configure headless browser using protractor on windows so that it can be run using team city without any GUI resolution issues?

Tags: node.js, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

How to configure headless browser using protractor on windows so that it can be run using team city without any GUI resolution issues?

Currently I am using chrome browser to run my UI automation test but at some page I am facing element not found issue due to resolution issue.

So I wanted to go for an headless browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Phantomjs is officially discontinued, so you must use headless Chrome. As for the instructions on how to set it up, follow [instructions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-headless-chrome)

Getting started with headless chrome can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Comment: I tried using args: chrome: {
                options: {
                    args: {
                        browser: "chrome",
                        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
                       }
                }
            },                       but I can see browser still opening.

Comment: it should be ```capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',

  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
   }
}```

Comment: Tried this too. Not working for me. Any other suggestion, please. Thanks in advance.